# Hibernate reverse engineering generates Embedded annotation

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jpa, annotations

Why does hibernate tool (as part of Jboss tools) generate embedded annotation (@Embedded) when reverse engineering ? I know its good practice to use embedded annotation but is there anyway of disabling this behaviour in Eclipse ?